# How to generate a series of repeated data based on its specified quantity in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

I would like to generate a series of repeated data based on its specified quantity in **Google Sheets**.

For example, in my first sheet, I have the following data:

[image: Sheet 1]

In the second sheet, I would like it to display a series of data repeated item based on its "Quantity" like this:

[image: Sheet 2]

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A:A&"♦", B:B)), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT(
 INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)), ",")&",", 
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B))))), ","))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in A1

```
={"Items Repeated";arrayformula(transpose(split(join("☺",rept(A2:A5&"☺",B2:B5)),"☺")))}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this:

```
=transpose
   (
     arrayformula 
       ( 
          split
             ( 
               join
                   (
                     "✪",rept(filter(C33:C,C33:C<>"") & "✪",filter(D33:D,C33:C<>""))
                   ),
               "✪"
             )
       )
   )
```

Comment: Filter isn't completely necessary here because if you repeat something "blank" times it returns blank. Are you thinking it will decrease loading times?

Comment: Thanks the comment, I appreciate it. 1st the reason we don't know how many row item he has that Will be repeated, 2nd any Cell in f column after repeating, not affect by this formula, any data Will not be blank, for the above begin from f44 down, 3rd if data is fixed i Will prefer to use as your formula.

Comment: And more, the repeating above, only for the result of the filter, not filtering for the result of the repeating, so the blank Will not be repeated, I think. I used rept(filter..., Not filter(rept....